# How to load a JNI .dylib file with a dependency without getting an UnsatifiedLinkError?

Tags: java, c, swift, java-native-interface

**Goal:** Link Java to Swift

**Problem:** I get an [`UnsatisfiedLinkError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) when trying to load a JNI `.dylib` file that is linked with a Swift `.dylib` file when calling [`System#loadLibrary(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)).

**Expected Behavior:** The dependency of the Java `.dylib` would be automatically loaded or the call to `System.loadLibrary("SwiftCode")` would load the dependency (the only solution I could come up with).

**Note:** I am combining [this github tutorial](https://gist.github.com/DmitrySoshnikov/8b1599a5197b5469c8cc07025f600fdb) and [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@bschlining/a-simple-java-native-interface-jni-example-in-java-and-scala-68fdafe76f5f) to create my JNI `.dylib` file and [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/HiImJulien/c79f07a8a619431b88ea33cca51de787) to create my Swift `.dylib` file.

**Full stacktrace:**

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/hillmacbookpro/IdeaProjects/JavaToSwift/src/native/libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib: dlopen(/Users/hillmacbookpro/IdeaProjects/JavaToSwift/src/native/libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: libSwiftCode.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/hillmacbookpro/IdeaProjects/JavaToSwift/src/native/libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2408)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2465)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2662)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1833)
    at helloworld.SwiftHelloWorld.<clinit>(SwiftHelloWorld.java:7)
```

**File Structure:**

```
src
  - helloworld
      - SwiftHelloWorld.java
  - native
      - libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib
      - libSwiftCode.dylib
```

**MCVE:**

`SwiftHelloWorld.java`:

```
package helloworld;

public class SwiftHelloWorld {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("SwiftCode"); // loading SwiftHelloWorld's dependency first
        System.loadLibrary("SwiftHelloWorld"); // exception thrown here, can't find dependency?
    }

    public static native void printHelloWorldImpl();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        printHelloWorldImpl();
    }

}
```

`libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib`: Created using these two terminal commands:

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)"; gcc -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin/" -o libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib -dynamiclib helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld.c libSwiftCode.dylib
```

and these files:

- `helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld.c`:

  ```
  #include <jni.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include "helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld.h"
  #include "helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld_swift.h"

  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld_printHelloWorldImpl
    (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {

      int result = swiftHelloWorld(42);
      printf("%s%i%s", "Hello World from JNI! ", result, "\n");

  }
  ```
- `helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld.h`: The auto-generated JNI header from
  `javac -h native/ helloworld/SwiftHelloWorld.java`
- `helloworld_SwiftHelloWorld_swift.h`:

  ```
  int swiftHelloWorld(int);
  ```

`libSwiftCode.dylib`: Created using `swiftc SwiftCode.swift -emit-library -o libSwiftCode.dylib` and the `SwiftCode.swift` file:

```
import Foundation

// force the function to have a name callable by the c code
@_silgen_name("swiftHelloWorld")
public func swiftHelloWorld(number: Int) -> Int {
    print("Hello world from Swift: \(number)")
    return 69
}
```

**Related Questions:**

- [Java JNI linking multiple libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307455/java-jni-linking-multiple-libraries), he/she gets an `UnsatifiedLinkError` but with the discription `undefined symbol: ...` (unanswered)
- Anything tagged with `JNI` and containing `UnsatifiedLinkError`

**Other Notes:** I am setting the Java virtual machine's options to `-Djava.library.path=src/native`, the parent directory of both of the `.dylib` files. I am using macOS.

**Edit:** I have tried preceding the command to compile `SwiftCode.swift` with `xcrun` as seen in [this article](https://medium.com/swift-programming/secret-of-swift-performance-fcc5d2a437a8) (under "Compile Swift code") but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS `ld` builds a library dependency's path into the binary. The loader loading `libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib` will only find `libSwiftCode.dylib` if the latter is in the current directory. Loading the dependency in Java doesn't work because for the loader it's a different library.

You can change the built-in path for `libSwiftCode.dylib` with the `-install_name` argument (i.e. `swiftc ... -Xlinker -install_name -Xlinker <your path>`). If you rebuild `libSwiftHelloWorld.dylib` afterwards it will reference the path that you gave.

Comment: This answer has probably saved me countless hours. Thanks! I have found that it makes sense to use a relative `install_name`, so that one just has to put the two dylibs into the same directory. A good explanation for macOS linking using `@loader_path`, `@rpath`, `install_name` etc. can be found at https://matthew-brett.github.io/docosx/mac_runtime_link.html